# DotNetOpenAuth Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Token Store

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently working on a small mobile project and I want to use DotNetOpenAuth to protect the API. I currently decided to use 4.3 of the OAuth 2.0 Spec "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant".

I downloaded the Samples and it has an Authorization Server sample which helped a lot so I managed to get everything working on that end. I authenticate the user with my custom auth provider using the CheckAuthorizeResourceOwnerCredentialGrant method. This later calls the CreateAccessToken method which return the Access Token successfully.

Now I know I need to store the Token to authorize the user on later requests.

That's where I'm a bit lost. Is there a way of doing this following DNOA best practices, without me having to bake this on my own? Maybe in the current samples?

Comment: Did you work this one out Michael?  I'm in the same situation but just cannot figure out what I need to do.

Comment: @Jammer Yup. I managed to tackle it. I created an MVC app that acts as a provider and my mobile apps just grab tokens from it, while making calls to the controllers I have a module that checks those tokens and assigns the users principals.